# Check boxes and sections in crm 2011

Tags: javascript, checkbox, dynamics-crm-2011, sections

I have section A,B,C. Each section has check boxes. The user must select atleast one check box from each section, if not a message pop is required. So for example if only a checkbox from section A is checked, the message must say "please check atleast one from Section B and C". How can I write this function? Please let me know

Answer (score 1):

There are two options, have an `onSave` function defined that performs the logic, or, if you want to give the user feedback, create onChange functions for each checkbox that marks all check boxes in the section as not being required when checked, and when unchecked and non of the other check boxes are checked, marks them all as required.